# Clarification on some terms in BO Universe Designer

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects, universe

What is the difference between variable(dimension) and indicator in BO Universe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Indicator" is not a type of universe object. The types are:
Dimension: a non-aggregatable data field, such as Customer Name, Store Address, etc. 
Measure: a field that can be aggregated (min, max, sum, count, etc). For example, Customer Count, Sales Amount. 
Detail: an attribute associated with a dimension.

A variable, in BO terms, is a user-defined formula that is created in a report, rather than in the universe.  For example if the universe has objects for Customer First Name and Customer Last Name, you could create a variable in the report named "Customer Full Name" that comcats the first and last name; this variable can then be displayed in the report.